# SQL updating multiple cells with values from a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-update, subquery, common-table-expression

The other day,I thought I found a very elegant way to update part of a set of cells. This is what I came up with :

```
Update mytable
Set ExternalLink = REPLACE (ExternalLink, R.UniqueID, R.ParentUniqueID)
From (
Select u.UniqueID, u.ParentUniqueID, RIGHT (mt.ExternalLink, 7) as EL
From uniqueidtable u
Join mytable mt
On EL = u.ParentUniqueID
Where mt.ExternalLink Like '%stringinurl%' ) R
```

I believe I got the idea from a stack question, but I can't find it in my history.

I can't seem to get more than one cell updated, even though the subquery returns several rows when tested alone. What's wrong with this and how can I tweak it to update multiple cells at a time?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have so many questions.

Comment: Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: @Beer_en_thu_si_asT: Tag database you are using .

Comment: If the query window is connected to the correct db, why do I need to tag it? Unless I'm not understanding what you mean by tag.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: It's a regular T-SQL environment through SSMS 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I came up with an answer. I'm not sure why a Table Expression did not work in this case, but here's what I came up with:

```
    UPDATE mytable
    SET ExternalLink = REPLACE(Ta.ExternalLink, T.ParentUniqueID, T.UniqueID)
    FROM mytable Ta
    JOIN UniqueIDtable
    ON RIGHT(Ta.ExternalLink, 7) = T.ParentUniqueID
    WHERE ExternalLink LIKE '%stringinurl%' AND ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(Ta.ExternalLink, 7)) = '1';
```

It seems I was just messing up the placement of the ID and parent ID in the replace. I also didn't count on the end of the URL string in the ExternalLink column to be anything but a numeric value, so that came up with some issues as well. It seems to be working for me now, so I've got that going for me.